# How to correctly add new entity with F# on MonoTouch

Tags: core-data, f#, xamarin.ios

I would like to know how to correctly add new objects to a CoreData datastore. The following code works, but I'm a bit surprised that I have to use new NSString and new NSNumber to set the values. Besides that I'm afraid that my code would lead to memory leaks.

```
let ed = NSEntityDescription.InsertNewObjectForEntityForName("Document", context)

ed.SetValueForKey(new NSString("title"), new NSString("title"))
ed.SetValueForKey(new NSString("file"), new NSString("file"))
ed.SetValueForKey(new NSString("base_name"), new NSString("base_name"))
ed.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber(123), new NSString("question_count"))
ed.SetValueForKey(new NSString("revision"), new NSString("revision"))
ed.SetValueForKey(new NSString("valid"), new NSString("valid"))

let error = context.Save()
```

Comment: Looks OK. I do no see any leaks here.

Answer (score 0):

That won't leak. The garbage collector (GC) will reclaim the memory of the created instances when no reference to them exists (e.g. after the method call).

OTOH you can do this with less code (at least with C#), e.g.

```
ed.SetValueForKey ((NSString) "title", (NSString) "title")

ed.SetValueForKey ((NSNumber) 123, (NSString) "question_count")
```

Note that it does not really changes what's happening (but I prefer that syntax).